# Is There any reason to use DHTML Or IIS in vb6?

Tags: iis, vb6, dhtml

I found that DHTML doesn't work in Mozilla or IE6+ . So I was asking is there any reason to use DHTML or IIS in vb6?

I am asking this because I wanted to know if there is any reason or any way to use DHTML for all browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old DHTML Application project type in VB6 is basically obsolete now.  Time passed it by and Microsoft has strongly deprecated most of the technologies it is based on.

"IIS Applications" (i.e. WebClasses) can still be viable since they don't rely on many client-side features.  Still, you may have to enable now-optional features in modern IIS versions in order to use them.  They've never been popular, and ASP.Net was their successor - which got a lot more love from Microsoft.